# Get the number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the number of rows of a studentID and then echo if the count is over 10.

This is what I wrote so far. But doesn't seem to work.

```
$findID = ID1231275;
$gipct = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(studentID) FROM classFees WHERE studentID = '".$findID."'");
if ($gipct>10) {
echo ("$gipct");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$searchID = 'ID1231275';
$gipct = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(studentID) as students FROM classFees WHERE studentID = '$searchID'");
$row = mysql_fetch_object($gipct);
if ($row->students >10) {
echo $row->students;
}
```

Btw, mysql_ functions are deprecated and can/will be removed in future versions of php, I recommend you to look at PDO statements or mysqli_ functions

Comment: `ID1231275` should be a string, not a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php > 5 then you must use mysqli instead of mysql class. Then try this:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','database');
$searchID = 'ID1231275';
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(studentID) FROM classFees WHERE studentID =? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $searchID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($gipct);
$stmt->fetch();
if ($gipct > 10) {
 echo ($gipct);
}
```

Comment: Where's the database connection in the mysqli_query()?

Comment: You used the procedural style on the query so you need to provide the database connection

Answer (score 0):

`$gipct` is a mysql resource. So you have to use the function `mysql_num_rows` to get all rows that are selected.

Thats in your case not working because you have a COUNT in your query so you get only one row.

In your case you have to fetch the data first.

```
$gipct = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(studentID) AS countout FROM classFees WHERE....");

$row = mysql_fetch_object($gpict);
if ($row->countout > 10) {
   echo ("$gipct");
}
```

Or the method with the `mysql_num_rows`

```
$gipct = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classFees WHERE student...");

if (mysql_num_rows($row) > 10) {
   echo ("$gipct");
}
```

But here you select all records which can be much slower as the first solution.